# Create view with hard coded values including order by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

I have a view that i created that reads from a table as well as includes hard coded values. The view was created as expected except i want to order by a column in the definition of the view.

View:

```
create VIEW [dbo].[RPTLV_PICKIDS] (   [Fixed],   [Item],   [Desc]    )   AS  select 0, 'test1', 'test1' union select 0, 'test2', 'test2'  union select 0,  cast(PickID as varchar(11)), cast(PickID as varchar(11))  FROM dbo.table group by pickid
```

As a note i don't have control of order by when running select.

The results i am looking for would be when i run following:

```
select * from dbo.RPTLV_PICKIDS order by item
```

Behind the scenes a query is just ran to select from the view which returns following:

```
Fixed     Item     Desc
0         1        1
0         2        2
0         test1    test1
0         test2    test2
```

Desired Results:

```
Fixed     Item     Desc
0         test1    test1
0         test2    test2
0         1        1
0         2        2
```

I need to alter creation of view somehow to have order by Item

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: A view is a presentation of some data, a bit like a table. The ordering should be specified by the query on the data. Explain why you don't have control of the select.

Comment: The base code runs the select which cannot be altered

Comment: You simply cannot do what you are trying to do the way you are trying to do it. What I mean is that there is one and only one way to ensure the ordering of data from any DBMS. That is by putting an order by on the final select statement. Consider what the order would be if you had to views, each with an order by, and you join them together. Which view's order by would take precedence? If you can't change the code that is running your query you are dead in the water. It is actually impossible.

Comment: @Sean Lange That what i was afraid of thanks for clarifying

Comment: As a work around i forgot sql orders brackets before numbers so when i used [test1] i got the results i was looking for

Comment: LOL but you don't have an order by on your query. What you have kludged will work for awhile. If you never have any more data it may continue to work indefinitely. But at some point it will fail. This article explains this phenomenon quite nicely. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx

Answer (score 0):

{knee-jerk reaction, total air code}

Since we're talking a custom sort then change your ORDER BY clause to use a CASE statement, like this..

```html
ORDER BY 
   CASE Item WHEN 'test1' THEN 1 WHEN 'test2' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END, 
   Item
```

Also views don't really handle ORDER BY (Richard's comment above) without some workaround like TOP 100 PERCENT, so if ordering really matters perhaps a Stored Procedure would be a better choice.

Comment: View doesn't know what Item is upon creation

Comment: ^^^ Ok.  Looking at the view T-SQL which I didn't do before, in that case we'd be talking throwing all of your T-SQL other than the sorting into a subquery, and calling it all plus doing the sorting from a main query.   Let me know if you'd like T-SQL for that and I'll crank it out as a separate answer.  Also just out of curiosity what's the purpose of the 'test1' and 'test2' rows?

Comment: TOP 100 PERCENT would probably be discarded by query optimizer, maybe TOP 10000 or some other value greater than maximum number of rows retrieved could be used - but that would be an ugly hack which really wouldn't be recommendable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select [col1],[col2],[col3] from (
    --just assign additional rank column to order by and then omit it in outer select query
    select 0 [rank], 0 [col1], 'test1' [col2], 'test1' [col3]

    union 

    select 0, 0, 'test2', 'test2'  

    union 

    select 1, 0,  
           cast(PickID as varchar(11)), 
           cast(PickID as varchar(11))  
    FROM dbo.table group by pickid

) order by [rank]
```